# Using Aviso Rook for validation in Clojure REST service

Tags: rest, clojure

I play with Rook (https://portal.aviso.io/#/document/open-source/rook/Current) for Clojure based REST services.

While the general layout of Rook is quite clear (implementing Verbs for different interfaces) I am not so clear if I grokked Rook's approach for POST bodies. I.e. implementing a POST, I can access the request body, yet I wonder if this is the intended way:

```
(defn create
  [ ^:request requ]
  (let [request-body (slurp (:body requ))]
     ...
   ))
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using the standard middleware, the contents of a body request is available deserialized as the value of the `:body-params` key of the request map.